# Filtering in pandas using regex expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas, filter

I´m doing some work in excel using pandas and python. I have something like this.

```
  ID         Actual Date
738564     01/21/2016
274628     02/12/2016
571749     03/30/2016
718563     10/01/2016
984739     11/30/2016
938511     12/24/2016
103216     07/16/2014
446754     08/06/2015
135654     02/01/2017
135614     01/16/2017
133346     01/16/2011
234682        N/A
238756       (none)
```

So i need to filter by date, but i just need to filter the year dates before november 2016( So i need to filter 2014, 2015, and between january and octuber of 2016 ). So basically after the filter i will have something like this

```
      ID       Actual Date
   738564   01/21/2016
   274628   02/12/2016
   571749   03/30/2016
   718563   10/01/2016
   103216   07/16/2014
   446754   08/06/2015
   133346   01/16/2011
   234682        N/A
   238756       (none)
```

The code i´m using for this is:

```
    regex = r"[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/2016"
df = pd.read_csv("Request.csv", keep_default_na=False)
df1 = df.loc[(df["Actual Date"].str.contains(r'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/2016') &
             (df["Actual Date"].str.contains("2015")) & 
             (df["Actual Date"].str.contains("2014")) &
             (df["Actual Date"].str.contains("2011")) &
             (df["Actual Date"].str.contains("(None)")) &
             (df["Actual Date"].str.contains("N/A"))))]
```

But when i run the code, i receive just the 2011, 2014 and 2015. The regular expression it´s not working for the 2016 dates. 
I'll really appreciate the help, and sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx is very powerful tool, but in this case there is a better approach:

```
In [180]: df
Out[180]:
        ID  ActualDate
0   738564  01/21/2016
1   274628  02/12/2016
2   571749  03/30/2016
3   718563  10/01/2016
4   984739  11/30/2016
5   938511  12/24/2016
6   103216  07/16/2014
7   446754  08/06/2015
8   135654  02/01/2017
9   135614  01/16/2017
10  133346  01/16/2011
11  234682         NaN
12  238756      (none)
```

let's convert it `datetime` dtype:

```
In [181]: df['ActualDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ActualDate'], errors='coerce')

In [182]: df
Out[182]:
        ID ActualDate
0   738564 2016-01-21
1   274628 2016-02-12
2   571749 2016-03-30
3   718563 2016-10-01
4   984739 2016-11-30
5   938511 2016-12-24
6   103216 2014-07-16
7   446754 2015-08-06
8   135654 2017-02-01
9   135614 2017-01-16
10  133346 2011-01-16
11  234682        NaT
12  238756        NaT
```

filtering using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [184]: df[(df['ActualDate'] < '2016-11-01') | df['ActualDate'].isnull()]
Out[184]:
        ID ActualDate
0   738564 2016-01-21
1   274628 2016-02-12
2   571749 2016-03-30
3   718563 2016-10-01
6   103216 2014-07-16
7   446754 2015-08-06
10  133346 2011-01-16
11  234682        NaT
12  238756        NaT
```

filtering using [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [186]: df.query("ActualDate < '2016-11-01' or ActualDate != ActualDate")
Out[186]:
        ID ActualDate
0   738564 2016-01-21
1   274628 2016-02-12
2   571749 2016-03-30
3   718563 2016-10-01
6   103216 2014-07-16
7   446754 2015-08-06
10  133346 2011-01-16
11  234682        NaT
12  238756        NaT
```

**UPDATE:** if you want to preserve original `Date` in string dtype:

```
In [190]: df
Out[190]:
        ID Actual Date
0   738564  01/21/2016
1   274628  02/12/2016
2   571749  03/30/2016
3   718563  10/01/2016
4   984739  11/30/2016
5   938511  12/24/2016
6   103216  07/16/2014
7   446754  08/06/2015
8   135654  02/01/2017
9   135614  01/16/2017
10  133346  01/16/2011
11  234682         NaN
12  238756      (none)
```

first add a new `datetime` column:

```
In [191]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Date'], errors='coerce')

In [192]: df
Out[192]:
        ID Actual Date       Date
0   738564  01/21/2016 2016-01-21
1   274628  02/12/2016 2016-02-12
2   571749  03/30/2016 2016-03-30
3   718563  10/01/2016 2016-10-01
4   984739  11/30/2016 2016-11-30
5   938511  12/24/2016 2016-12-24
6   103216  07/16/2014 2014-07-16
7   446754  08/06/2015 2015-08-06
8   135654  02/01/2017 2017-02-01
9   135614  01/16/2017 2017-01-16
10  133346  01/16/2011 2011-01-16
11  234682         NaN        NaT
12  238756      (none)        NaT
```

filtering:

```
In [194]: df.drop('Date', 1).loc[(df['Date'] < '2016-11-01') | df['Date'].isnull()]
Out[194]:
        ID Actual Date
0   738564  01/21/2016
1   274628  02/12/2016
2   571749  03/30/2016
3   718563  10/01/2016
6   103216  07/16/2014
7   446754  08/06/2015
10  133346  01/16/2011
11  234682         NaN
12  238756      (none)


In [196]: df.query("Date < '2016-11-01' or Date != Date").drop('Date', 1)
Out[196]:
        ID Actual Date
0   738564  01/21/2016
1   274628  02/12/2016
2   571749  03/30/2016
3   718563  10/01/2016
6   103216  07/16/2014
7   446754  08/06/2015
10  133346  01/16/2011
11  234682         NaN
12  238756      (none)
```

Comment: ok, i think the best idea is convert the date to datetime, but some values for th fate are None or NA, and i need to show this values too. Any option to do it, cause i think datetime do not accept strings.

The code is something like this

Comment: @CarlosArronteBello, do you want to have those rows where `Date` is `None` or `NaN` in the resulting data set (after filtering)?

Comment: yes please i need None and NA also all the dates before octuber 2016(including octuber). And thank you so much

Comment: ok looks that´s going to work for me, let me try the code, just a quick question, the return will be NaT or will be the string for None and Na and also the date format can be the mm/dd/yyyy, sorry for the bother, i´m basically new in this. And thanks for the help

Comment: if you want to be able to use vectorized (read fast) operations on `ActualDate` column, then you want to have it as `datetime64` dtype. That would also mean that you'll have `NaT` (Not a Time) instead of all values which couldn't be converted to dates and you will have default representation (the way it's shown on the screen): yyyy-mm-dd. You can convert it to string using whatever format you want, but you will lose flexibility and you you'll have to work with strings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134630/discussion-between-carlos-arronte-bello-and-maxu).